# npm install -g cordova windows 7 exits unexpectedly without any error

Tags: node.js, cordova

I am trying to install cordova using cmd npm install -g cordova.

the installation stops unexpectedly without any error.

I have not found any solution

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqy1o.png)

Comment: Hmm that's weird. Did you check if it installed? You can run _cordova -v_

Comment: That might be a networking problem related to `npm`. Check this [link](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7862) for some workarounds.